# How does an android activity interact with app-widget (Home screen widgets)?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

If I have an activity, so how can I use some of its methods (functionalities) in android widgets. Do I have to recreate the logic? What are the ways of interaction? Through intent or through service? Please please reply.

Update: I have a .java class that implements Parcelable and contains the method that returns the list. I want that list in my widget.

```
public Stores getStoreListings() {
        Log.i("List val","mStoreListings");
        return mStoreListings;
    }
```

Can I use Intent in my app widget to get this method or variable? This is not an activity..

---

UPDATE2: Using Async task, its not working also..Where I am going wrong?? PLease help..

```
public class ListViewWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int []appWidgetIds){
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_layout);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,ListViewWidget.class);

        String url=String.valueOf("https://api.paypal.com/v1/stores?view=local&lat=37.3756096&lng=-121.9239449&radius=50&count=20&start_id=1&country_code=US");

        FetchTask fetchTask=new FetchTask();
        //fetchTask.appWidgetManager=appWidgetManager;
        //fetchTask.onPostExecute(updateViews,context);
        fetchTask.execute();
        //context.startService(new Intent(context,UpdateService.class));
    }
    public static class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<URL,Integer,Stores>{

        String text=null;
        @Override
        protected Stores doInBackground(URL... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext=new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("https://api.paypal.com/v1/stores?view=local&lat=37.3756096&lng=-121.9239449&radius=50&count=20&start_id=1&country_code=US");

            Stores newList=new Stores();
            try{

                HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpGet,localContext);
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                text=String.valueOf(entity);


                //assign the list to the the correct entity type
                //newList=..;
                Log.i("Inside on update with Http call","Text"+text);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return newList;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(RemoteViews updateViews,Context context){

            Intent intent=new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");

            PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, text);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next, pendingIntent);

            // Push update for this widget to the home screen
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, ListViewWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about App Widgets (home screen widgets)? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @athor I am talking about app widgets. So I have an activity that uses service to display certain data. One of them is like getting nearby places to my location. Now I want to create a widget for it so do I need to implement the whole logic in widget or can I reuse that logic in it through some callback methods or intent or service? I am trying to create a widget similar to Flipboard (updates news) or google plus widget that updates your latest notification on home screen?  So has the entire logic been reimplemented???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same server side logic, but you probably want to copy and paste it to a new service.

App Widgets work differently with their lifecycle. If you want your app widget to update periodically, you set that in your app widget config xml. Android will then call your provider when it is time to update the data.

At that point is where you would start your service, where you can reuse the logic to fetch whatever data you need. The only different is once the fetching of the data is done, it needs to be sent to the widget provider and not the activity.

Thats a basic overview of widgets, but to answer your question, it is best to re implement your logic to suit the app widget lifecycle.

Comment: So I can reuse my activity logic..perfect!! To fetch the data, what are the ways? As in I should create an object of an activity class and call their methods or create some handlers or pass through intents?

Comment: Your logic to fetch the data shouldn't be in your activity. It should be in a AsyncTask or IntentService (which run in the background). You can reuse that logic from the AsyncTask or IntentService, but not the activity logic.

Comment: I am not clear here now.. What can I reuse and what I cannot?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Just want to confirm that Do I have to make network and API calls again in service or I can just create an instance and use them. I am not using AsyncTask.

Comment: And can you just one time tell me what reuse means? As in copy-paste or creating instances and using them? PLease please guide..

Comment: The easiest way would be to just copy and paste.

Comment: Okay..I have done that..Now I also want a list from my services that has been pre-populated. The list is stored in a var mList. I want that list to be in my widget. This list is changed as per your location. So how should I use this var-mList in app-widget?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have activity and service (or AsyncTask) for now, right? What athor is trying to say - your data-fetching logic should be in Service or AsyncTask. But according to AppWidget lifecycle you need to use Service to fetch new data on schedule and to update your widget views (via RemoteViews). 
Thats where you can reuse your data-fetching logic - for example, if you had AsyncTask in your activity - you can use instance of same AsyncTask in this new Service.

UPD.
No. Usually, you should start your own service class derived from IntenService (for example) with intent from your widget. Then in service you can just simply get all your data in the same way you did it before.

Check this: AppWidgetProvider extends BroadcastReceiver class. 
"
A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.

In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the NotificationManager API. For the latter, **you can use Context.startService() to send a command to the service**
"
More details on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Ok..So for AsyncTask, I can create an instance in my service class.          And by reuse you mean copy-paste or using through object?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Just want to confirm that Do I have to make network and API calls again in service or I can just create an instance and use them. I am not using AsyncTask.

Comment: If you are not using async task, then yes - you need to place network and api calls in service. For reusing your code you can place network and api calls from your activity to async task (implemented as separate class), then instantiate and run async task object in both places - in activity when app launched and in service for updating app widget.

Comment: No. Usually, you should start your own service class derived from IntenService (for example) with intent from your widget. THen in service you can just simply get all your data in the same way you did it before.

Comment: Thanks for all your patience but I am not able to understand now at all. I have tried Async task also. I am totally confused and lost track I feel..Please check my another update with async task and will be really helpful of you to get me to right track..